# $f'$ being continuous on [a,b] $\implies$ $f$ is uniformly differentiable

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

suppose $f'$ is continuous on [a,b] and $\epsilon>0$. Prove that:

$\exists \delta>0$ s.t. $|(f(t)-f(x)/(t-x)) - f'(x)|<\epsilon$

whenever $0<|t-x|<\delta$

with
$a\leq x \leq b$, $a\leq t \leq b$.

I'm having a lot of problems with this problem. It is #8 from chapter 5 in baby Rudin. Can anyone offer some helpful insights here? Thanks!

Comment: Use the mean value theorem and the fact that $f’$ is uniformly continuous.